# Axiomatising Wellorder

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

It may be of use to recall what a strict total order is; namely a binary relation satisfying irreflexivity, transitivity and totality, as formalised below: 
$$\forall x(\neg P_{1}(x,x))$$
$$\forall x \forall y \forall z((P_{1}(x,y) \land P_{1}(y,z)) \to P_{1}(x,z))$$
$$\forall x \forall y (P_{1}(x,y) \lor x \dot{=}y \lor P_{1}(y,z))$$

Furthermore, a *well-order* is a strict total order, $\mathcal{A}=\langle A; <;-\rangle $ for  which there is no infinite sequence $\{x_{j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements in $A$, such that $x_{j+1}<x_{j}$ for all $j \in\mathbb{N}$.

Now,  what I want to show is:

> Well-order is not axiomatizable.

My idea so far has been to suppose that $\Gamma$ axiomatizes the class of well-orderings, add countably many constants $c_{j}$ and show that $\Gamma \cup \{c_{j+1}<c_{j}:j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has a model. However, I find it difficult to follow through on the last step, namely show that $\Gamma \cup \{c_{j+1}<c_{j}:j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, which is why I ask for help from this forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there.

> Suppose $\Gamma$ is a set of first-order sentences with a non-logical binary relation symbol $P$ such that, for every $n$, there is a model of $\Gamma$ in which $P$ is a well-order on at least $n$ elements of the domain.

If this supposition doesn't hold, i.e. if for any set of sentences $\Gamma$ there is a $n$ such that models of $\Gamma$ can't have well-orderings longer than $n$, that already means that there is no general theory $\Gamma$ whose models of its relation symbol are just  the well-orderings (finite and infinite). So grant the supposition.

Then add new constants $c_i$ (distinct for every natural nuumber $i$), and consider the theory $\Gamma^+$ which is $\Gamma$ plus every $P(c_{j + 1}, c_j)$. Any finite selection of  $\Gamma^+$'s axioms has a model, given our supposition. [There will be $n$ constants $c_j$ featured; take a model where $P$ is a well-order on at least $n$ elements, and then use the $c_j$ to name $n$ elements in the right order.] So by compactness $\Gamma^+$ has a model. But this model will have an infinite downward $P$-chain, so isn't well-ordered. So the reduct of this model to the original language withough the added constants will be a non-well-ordered model of $\Gamma$. So $\Gamma$ can't be a theory whose models for its binary relation $P$ are all and only the well-orderings.

Answer (score 2):

Another method, which may be slightly simpler, is to use ultraproducts and Los theorem, if you have studied about them.

Note that $\cal N=\langle\Bbb N,<\rangle$ is a strict well-order. Suppose that it was axiomatizable then every ultraproduct of well-orders would be a well-order. Consider any free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, $\cal U$ then the structure: $$\cal M=N^\Bbb N/U$$

Should be a well-order as well, since by Los theorem both $\cal N$ and $\cal M$ have the same first-order theory. However it is not hard to find a decreasing sequence in $\cal M$. Such sequence, for example, is letting $f_0$ to be the identity function, and $f_{n+1}(k)=f_n(k-1)$ (and $0$ for $k=0$).

Comment: Always beware set theorists who say things like "... may be slightly simpler" :-)

Comment: Peter, well sure. But my daddy used to say "Always beware of logicians, plain logician that is [read: not set theorists, model theorists, proof theorists, etc.]". So I guess we're even on that one! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is it easy to show that there is a strictly decreasing sequence in $\mathcal{M}$ of length $\aleph_1$ ?

Comment: @Elif: I suppose easy depends on what you already know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, of course :) I think using a diagonal argument in order to show given sequence is uncountable can work. However, I couldn't find an another sequence different than you already gave. If you suggest something, I can study on it.

Comment: @Elif: That's not guaranteed to work. You can show that any bounded [well-ordered] sequence of reals can be extended to an even longer one, but you cannot produce an uncountable sequence of reals (this works even better with the rationals, since any sequence can be taken as a sequence of rational numbers). You might want to read about $\mathfrak t$, the tower number, or about Hausdorff gaps in general.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for corrections and suggestions. However, $\mathcal{M}$ is still not well-ordered even if we didn't find such a sequence of length $\aleph_1$, right? I mean, the latter condition is stronger than the former one.

Comment: @Elif: Yes, "not a well-order" means that there is an infinite decreasing sequence. Having one of length $\omega_1$ is a significant step further.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What about this idea? Suppose $\alpha <\gamma< \omega_1$ and we have a strictly decreasing sequence $(f_{\alpha}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N})_{\alpha<\gamma}$. If we define $f_{\gamma}(n):\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $f_{\gamma}(n)=\min_{\alpha < \gamma}\{f_{\alpha}(n)\}$, then I think we can prove $f_{\gamma}<f_{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha<\gamma$. What do you think?

Comment: @Elif: How can you guarantee that this is strictly decreasing? Why isn't the minimum always $0$ somehow?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, then it needs an extra condition. We may assume functions in the sequence are all unbounded, maybe? Or, we may say that $f_{\gamma}(n)\neq 0$ on an infinite set,  and it is $ \min_{\alpha < \gamma} \{ f_{\alpha}(n) \}$ otherwise.  I try to use transfinite induction because we already a countable sequence satisfying this property. If I can go further, I think this proves the existence of decreasing sequence of size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @Elif: I think that at this point it's best if you just ask a separate question, rather than engaging here in the comments. I'm afraid that I don't have all that much free time, and someone else might offer a better and quicker answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I want to think more. But if I couldn't find a way to solve this, I will do that. Thanks.